# Django admin interface missing css styling in dokerize django production

Tags: python, django, docker, production

The user interface is working well, and all CSS styling and static files are served correctly, but the admin interface is missing CSS styling. I looked at similar posts but in those posts, people had the issue with both the user and the admin interface. My issue is only with the admin interface.

Please see my static file settings below from `settings.py`:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

Docker File:

```
FROM python:3.8.5-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt .

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc openssh-server libev-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev

RUN echo PermitRootLogin yes >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
RUN echo root:newadminpasswd | chpasswd

RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . .
RUN cp ./.env.example .env
EXPOSE 8003 22

# Copy the rest of the code.
COPY . /app/
RUN chmod +x start-server.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/app/start-server.sh"]
```

start-server.sh File:

```
echo ".......... start executing collecstatic ........."
python3 manage.py collectstatic
echo ".......... start executing makemigrations ........."
python3 manage.py makemigrations
echo ".......... start executing migrate ........."
python3 manage.py migrate
# python3 manage.py seed_admin_user
# python3 manage.py seed_super_user
echo "Docker started...."
python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8003
```

Comment: Which responses do you get for the assets loaded by the admin? There should be an erro response which could help.

Comment: Error is not coming only the assets are not loading where as local is working fine . On product I checked the path of the statics folder not giving I did check with code inspect